# Android back button action issue after applying fix for "Application Error : connection to the server was unsuccessful" in sencha touch app

Tags: android, html, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My sencha touch app was facing "***Application Error***:Connection to server was unsuccessful" error in Android devices , as my app includes a lot of backend fetching on startup.

The general fix for this is increasing the time out interval in `MyAppActivity.java` , like this:

```
<preference name="load-url-timeout" value="60000" />
```

Well, this is not applicable in my case as this will make the app UI stuck during the timeout interval period and such a delay is not appreciated in my app.

Another the fix I tried and found working is this one, suggested from Phonegap community:

[Community-powered support for PhoneGap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/application_error_the_connection) and [Fix for PhoneGap: Connection to server was unsuccessful](http://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/)

Here is what I did:

- renamed current `index.html` as main.html
- created a new `index.html` and called `main.html` from it:
  [image]

This works fine but the issue is The **app won't get closed on android backbutton action**  !
On back button click, the app starts loading again,like a refresh.
ie, the call goes back to the new `index.html` and the `main.html` is called again.

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MyAppActivity.java

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
              if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                  moveTaskToBack(true);
              }
              return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

EDIT: This will push your app to background. If you want to exit the app, replace  `moveTaskToBack(true);` by `finish();`

Comment: Thanks..this works...but the app won't get quit, is pushed to background..like home button action